# Flask not executing Javascript in static directory

Tags: javascript, python, flask

**Overview**: I am using Ubuntu 14.04 in virtualbox, running the Python based Flask module to host a local portal with html, javascript, jquery and php elements.

**Expected Outcome**: I have a static JS file called test.js that I expect to be served when the template portal.html loads.

**Issue**: The HTML page loads correctly, I receive a GET status 200 for test.js in the terminal, however the JS script does not execute (i.e. 'Twitter' is not present in the tags with id="screen_name"). I checked localhost:5000/static/js/test.js and the script is present. I tried including the exact same JS script directly in the HTML rather than as a static file and it worked fine.

**Question**: If my static JS script in being requested why is it not executing?

**Directory Structure**:

```
portal
    - portal_server.py
    - templates
        - portal.html
    - static
        - img
        - css
        - js
            - test.js
```

**Contents of test.js**:

```
var x = document.getElementById('screen_name');
x.textContent = 'twitter';
```

**Relevant element of HTML**:

```
<h3 id="screen_name"></h3>
```

**Script element of HTML**:

```
<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>
```

Comment: `<script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/test.js') }}"></script>`  how does that come out in the HTML sent to the clinet ?

Comment: If I understand your question it appears `<script src="/static/js/handlesdb.js"></script>` in the browser's inspect element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One possible explanation:

If your `<script>` tag is in the `<head>` of your document, it will execute before the body is loaded. In this situation, the element with Id `"screen_name"` won't yet be loaded, and thus `var x = document.getElementById('screen_name');` will not contain the result you expect.

If this is the case, try moving the `<script>` tag to the end of your document.

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what was happening. Works as expected now.